# Navigation inside UIPopoverViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIPopoverViewController with a UIView in it.  When I push a button inside the UIView I want it to present a new UIView inside of the UIPopoverViewController.  However it keeps taking up the full screen.  How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: With 'full screen', do you mean the complete popover, or do you mean the complete display of the device?

Comment: I mean the complete display of the device. I would love for it to be the full screen of the popover

Answer (score 0):

Create a new UIPopoverViewController inside to open the new view
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the content size of the popover view each time you change its content view for it to maintain your custom sizing.

Apple docs on `popoverContentSize`:

> This property represents the size of the content view that is managed
>   by the view controller in the contentViewController property. The
>   initial value of this property is set to value in the view
>   controller’s contentSizeForViewInPopover property. Changing the value
>   of this property overrides the default value of the current view
>   controller. The overridden value persists until you assign a new
>   content view controller to the receiver. Thus, **if you want to keep
>   your overridden value, you must reassign it after changing the content
>   view controller**.